# Within the context of D3.js, what is a reusable chart?

Tags: d3.js

I tried searching for this online, but I was not able to find any proper explanation online. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in this article (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/), a reusable chart can be used for inserting a chart into any DOM element, any number of times within the same page. And it also lets you use different data each time the chart is rendered.

Comment: Thank you for the superfast response!

Comment: You're welcome. It's basically a literal definition of the word `reusable`.